# Replace text on the fly with JS

Tags: javascript

Good day all!

Now I am no expert in JS, but I now how to use it and how to read it (for the most part).

What I want to do is...

Inside a form element I have the usual suspects. But in just one text area I want a way to swap words on the fly. For example.

"... this and that"

would be swapped to

"...this &amp ; (the ascii code for &) that"

and the same for a few other ascii codes.

Can it be done? Can anyone point me to a tutorial.

Thanks all for your time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "on the fly"? How often do you want this to occur?

Comment: `&amp;` is not the ASCII code for `&`, but the HTML entity.

Comment: Also, any frameworks (jQuery)? only helps on adding the event handlers mind you.

Comment: Replacements like these are usually done in server side code. There's no way to guarantee that your Javascript is executed at all, so it's not safe to rely on that.

Comment: Do you want to change on hover? on click? when would you like the text to be replaced?

Comment: Open up a book and learn about JavaScript regular expressions.

Comment: @PlatinumAzure By on the fly I mean. Person typing "&" or "and" hits space and the word is changed to `&amp;` right away. @GolezTrol Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The replacement itself is just a case of `out = in.replace(/\band\b/g,"&amp;")`, but where you get `in` from and what you do with `out` is up to you (unless you can elaborate further in your question).

Just be careful what you do - replacing words can be tricky and lead to undesired results. Take [this blog post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/10/obscenity-filters-bad-idea-or-incredibly-intercoursing-bad-idea.html) for example. I think that covers the issue pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a simple function that takes some JSON and then replaces text based on the JSON. Example:

```
var theObj = {
    "and":"&amp;",
    "<":"&lt;",
    ">":"&gt;"
};

function replace( theString, myJSON ){

    for( prop in myJSON ){
         theString = theString.replace( \prop\g, myJSON[prop] );
    }
    return theString;
}
```

And [that](http://jsfiddle.net/dUe5t/2/) should give you a place to start off from.